# Command key mulitple text selection no longer works in Word for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

Command + hold multiple text selection does not work any more in Word for Mac.
That is so strange because it is a very useful function.
Any help for multiple text selection in Word for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the temporary solution for the issue in Word for Mac 2016:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/multiple-select-using-command-on-mac-is-gone/36450ab6-03f4-4724-9542-4cdfe9736209?auth=1

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.